# Each Radiobutton for each form or 1 Form for all radiobuttons?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

i have a problem with this homepage.

I have to create a Site like this:

```
status   create work finished

Item1    *       o      o
Item2    o       *      o
Item3    o       o      *
```

(* = checked, o = unchecked)

Now as admin i have the rights to change the status of the each Item.

For example when i change the Status from Item1 to "work" it should send a Form and update it in Database.

My Problem is know, should i create for each pair of 3 radiobuttons 1 Form?

But when i create 1 for all Buttons i will have problems to know which status have changed.
Only compare with each Database entry.

Before someone ask, i should use radiobuttons.
Hope someone could help.

Greetz

Demonking

Edit: Sorry, eomeone have misunderstand me.
I meant if i would be faster and better with :

```
<form method="post">
 Item 1 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="create" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="work" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="finished" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
</form>

<form method="post">
 Item 2 <input type="radio" name="item2" value="create" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item2" value="work" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item2" value="finished" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
</form>
```

or

```
<form method="post">
 Item 1 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="create" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="work" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="finished" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 Item 2 <input type="radio" name="item2" value="create" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item2" value="work" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item2" value="finished" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>


</form>
```

because of Performance with PHP/MySQL

Comment: group the radio buttons per item and use a single form - then use the `change` event to decide what changed when ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use one form and then perform a database update for all values.
And then I'd use javascript to augment the page, i.e. keep it working for clients that don't support/execute javascript but have a submit-handler that only sends values that have changed in clients that do execute javascript.
And then I'd do some benchmarking/profiling to check if the "only changed values" versionn really is faster/better than the "update all values" version. If not the javascript part is history ;-)

Comment: Hello, i benchmarked it with 100 000 elements and changed all status from each item
    Query OK, 128683 rows affected (1.16 sec)

Answer (score 1):

Give every radio button a proper `name` and `value`. Then you can check which radiobutton is selected.

Give every radio button for the same item the same name, but give it a different value. Then you have one value for every item after submit.

Eg. $_POST['item1'] should contain 'create', 'work' or 'finished'.

Then use javascript to detect which one is changed.

Comment: this could be a problem with 1000 items :/ 
i could iterate it with a foreach, but will have to update all rows

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how it should work, I think you can figure out the rest. And YES you need 3 radiobuttons for all three items.

```
<form method="post">
 Item 1 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="create" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="work" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 <input type="radio" name="item1" value="finished" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
</form>
```