# Should I make 1 form for each upvote button or 1 form for all the buttons?

Tags: html, django

Let's say I'm making some page where you can upvote several items in a list. Using django templates I might make a form encompassing the upvote button, or encompassing the entire list of posts, i.e.:

```
<ul>
{% for post in posts %}
<li> {{ post.url }}
<form action="/upvote" method="POST">
<button name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" type="submit">Upvote</button>
</form> </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

or

```
<form action="/upvote" method="POST">
<ul>
{% for post in posts %}
<li> {{ post.url }} <button name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" type="submit">Upvote</button>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</form>
```

Which one is better practice?

I guess this could be a duplicate of this question: [Each Radiobutton for each form or 1 Form for all radiobuttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742829/each-radiobutton-for-each-form-or-1-form-for-all-radiobuttons)

Comment: Ajax is the only practical solution.

Comment: jquery is a high-level interface for Ajax right? (new to all this)

Comment: yes, you can use jquery ajax.